# HTML: upload-form in an other form

Tags: html

I have a little problem with an upload-form within an other form (call it data-form).
I know it is not possible to put a form into an other.

So I would need to put it after my data-form.

But I need the upload-form controls in the middle of my data-form because of optical and structural reasons.
The file-upload should also perform other actions and not the same than the data-form.

So any idea how can I make the upload-form after my data-form but visible in it or any other ideas to handle this?

I am using javascirpt and php also.

thanks and best wishes for 2011!

br,chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it is not possible to put a form into an other.

Nesting HTML forms [is not valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html) and results into undefined behavior which could vary between browsers. Here's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation).

Answer (score 0):

You could leave some space in your design and then nest the form (*visually*) in the other one with CSS and absolute positioning..

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `position: absolute` that might work depending on your layout, I had the idea of using a Flash based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org). That process works separately from the surrounding form. However, it creates a dependency on Flash and does not degrade gracefully (i.e. if Flash is not present, it does not work at all).