# Building multiple form tags on a single asp page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to be able to put a form tag within another form tag.  Here is what the master page is structured as:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="test.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">

-----------CONTENT PLACE HOLDER--------------

</form>
```

Inside my content place holder i want to put another form:

```
<form id="test" action="test.ashx" method="post">
</form>
```

My jquery is trying to .prop this form's (id: #test)  action attribute, but it can never find it because the outside form is not letting it.  The outside form has a "runat="server"" but the inside one does not.  Any ideas of how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you want multiple `<form>` tags?

Comment: Sharepoint comes custom with it in there, I just didnt want to modify the master page and screw everything else up so I was looking for a quick fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at these to SO Questions and their answers:

1. [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)
2. [How do you overcome the html form nesting limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation)

In a nutshell you shouldn't be nesting forms.

Answer (score 0):

Are both forms in your DOM? The outer form can't "hide" the inner one from jQuery. `$('form#test')` should still get it. Just make sure you do not reuse the same id in that page.