# How to create nested froms to create values in two different table at once in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was stuck with a different scenario like say for example i have model movies and the other is releases. I want to create a new form in the apps/views/movies/new.html.erb. In the new i wanna have the fields for movies table eventually ill be having a form for it and at the same time i want to add the movie release information to the other table releases.Like it will be nested form as follows

<%= form_for(@movies)......%>

<% files for movies table %>

2nd form <%=form_for :releases %>

```
   <% fields for releases table%>
```

so form one carries the data to movies table when user clicks on submit button. But i want to pass the the values to release table also with this click using a nested form. Is it possible to have nested forms. If so i wanted some help on how it can be achieved exactly. Help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for(@movies) do |f| %>
# fields for movie
  <%= f.fields_for :releases do |nested_f| %>
#fields for your nested form releases
  <% end %>
<% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Also in Movie.rb model add this line. `accepts_nested_attributes_for :releases`
More information [there](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Comment: Its very important on how we write a submit button. Im looking for how we could write it Mikahail.

Comment: im update my answer. basically, you only need submit for main form, nested form doesnt require submit button. Cheers!

Comment: Cool. I have tried it but the problem is values are getting created in movies table but not in the releases table.

Comment: Can you post your db schema for movie and release tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think HTML allows nested forms, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation).