# What is the purpose of the new "form" attribute on the "object" element in HTML5?

Tags: forms, html

In HTML5, the `object` element now has a `form` attribute.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-fae-form

This attribute associates the `object` element with a form.  I'm trying to understand purpose (or result or impact) of this association.  I've figured out a couple things:

1) It allows the `object` element to appear outside of the `form` element:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-attributes

2) It is used to construct the data set:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#categories

Is the object submitted with the rest of the form inputs?  Does the server (to whom the form is submitted) now have access to this object (via POST) for processing?  What am I missing?

**Edit**:  Still hoping for answers for the 2 questions above regarding form submission...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the W3 site, it sounds like this solves a pretty big problem with HTML4:  "This feature allows authors to work around the lack of support for nested form elements."  http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#form-owner

Comment: Help me understand, @Robert, how a lack of supported for nested form elements is a problem.  I can't say I've ever wanted nested forms.

Comment: @james do a search on this site for "nested forms" and you'll see all kinds of people trying to do this for legit reasons. here's one particularly well stated scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation