# Conflict using multiple forms javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I'm using two different forms - one is to retrieve radio button, another is as submission form. Problem is, I cannot use both the form actions at a time.

```
<table id="newImageTable" border="1" style="position:absolute; ">
<?
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($image_query)) {?>
    <form name="radioForm">
    <tr>
    <td><img border="0" src="<?=$row['image_path']?>" /></td>
    <td>
    <input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="<?=$row['image_name']?>" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
<?}?>
<tr>
<td width="60%">
<!--<input type="file" id="image" /><input type="button" id="imagePathButton" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadImagePath()" />-->
<form name="submitForm" action="http://128.233.104.33/passimagemodels/uploadServer.php?dbname=<? echo $dbname ?>" method="post" target="foo" enctype="multipart/form-data"                                                                                         
onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=200,height=200,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
   Upload New Image: <input name="myfile" type="file" id="imageBox" />
   <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" onclick=""/>
   </form></td>
   <td width="10%">
   <input type="button" value="Use selected image" id="useImageButton" onclick="post_value();"/>
   </td></tr>  
</table>
```

javascript code:

```
function getRadioValue() {
for (index=0; index < document.radioForm.imageRadio.length; index++) {
        if (document.radioForm.imageRadio[index].checked) {
    var radioValue = document.radioForm.imageRadio[index].id;
    return radioValue;
        }
}
}

function post_value(){
      alert('im');
      var selected_Image = getRadioValue();

      if (selected_Image == null){
         alert('Please Select an Image');
      }
      else{
           window.opener.document.getElementById(imageId).value = selected_Image;
           self.close();
      }
 }
```

Here if I put the `radioForm` outside the table, `getRadioValue` function works fine but `Upload` button does not submit the `submitForm`. And if I surround one `<tr>` with `radioForm` scenario is just vice-versa. Are there any restrictions on nesting forms?

Comment: You do not get *two* forms, you get *n+1* forms where *n* is the number of records in your result set (which you are calling *$image_query* by the way). What are you trying to achieve by multiple forms?

Answer (score 2):

**Scroll to the bottom if you want to skip the explanation, and get to the solution.**

You're creating multiple forms with the same name. `document.radioForm` will only refer to the first form, which is probably not desired. To solve it, place the form tags outside the `while` loop.

See below for a simplified overview of your problem, without loss of generality):

Current situation (document.radioForm.imageRadio.length = 1):

```
<!-- Only the first form is selected by JS. All of the others are ignored-->
<form name="radioForm"><input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="imag1" /></form>
<form name="radioForm"><input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="imag2" /></form>
<form name="radioForm"><input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="imag3" /></form>
<!-- Et cetera -->
```

Desired situation (`<form>` placed **outside** the `while` loop):

```
<form name="radioForm">
    <input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="image1" />
    <input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="image2" />
    <input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="image3" />
</form>
```

**Fixed code**
One form is enough to meet your wishes. The form will only be submitted when you click at the `<input type="submit" .. />` button. Since the `name` attribute of your previous "second" form is obsolete, I've omitted it without breaking any code.

```
<form name="radioForm"
     action="http://128.233.104.33/passimagemodels/uploadServer.php?dbname=<? echo $dbname ?>"
     method="post" target="foo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table id="newImageTable" border="1" style="position:absolute;">
<?
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($image_query)) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><img border="0" src="<?=$row['image_path']?>" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="imageRadio" id="<?=$row['image_name']?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?}?>
    <tr>
        <td width="60%">
            <!--<input type="file" id="image" /><input type="button" id="imagePathButton" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadImagePath()" />-->
            <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" />
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
           <input type="button" value="Use selected image" id="useImageButton" onclick="post_value();" />
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
</form>
```

I have adjusted only one thing: The `onsubmit` event handler have been removed. It serves no purpose, and would be a *huge* annoyance to the user.

Answer (score 1):

nesting form isn't allowed, check [How do you overcome the html form nesting limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation)
 the result unpreditable but you can use Javascript to workaround with it.

Checkout jQuery serialize example. see how it extract values, and then submit from via DOM.
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

In your case, file upload form should be the parent, because you need its encode type to work. Or you can optionally iframe it, using the above technique to reorganize data.