# using Ajax to post part of the HTML page

Tags: javascript, ajax

-Edited-

Hello,

I have a page which contains two forms,I would like to send only the second form using post method.

The form has a valid function which checks valid date, email , etc.

I would like to send the second form without leaving the page , only to send the second form.As far as I know it is doable with AJAX but I'm not sure how to execute it.

Here is an example of the code

Client Side

```
<body>
<div> ....

<form id='f1'>....</form>
<script> //validation functions, at the end of the main validation function there is a            //code that submits the second form , the one i intend to send.
</script>
<form id='f2'  action='http://mysite/goToMyHandler.cs...>
...some input controls...
<input type='button' value='send' onclick='executeValidation();'>
</form>
</body>
```

Server Side

myHandler.cs:

...saves data from

```
Response.Write('Form has been successfully sent');
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by *"to post a part of a page"*?

Comment: nested `<form>`s? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation

Comment: I don't want the whole page to be sent , I want to stay at the same page and let only 'myform' be sent to the action adress of the second form.

Comment: what javascript library are you using

Comment: Your question is still not very clear. Do you intend to send the contents of the `form` tag, or the values of the tags *inside* `form`? It may be best to add an example of the data that you wish to transmit to the question. Maybe even a signature, or simplified pseudocode of the server-side logic to help us understand.

Comment: This kind of problems are very often here on StackOverflow and you people need to learn to "guess" a context. For example, OP is learning client-side programming but he may not know it's called that way. But he tries to explain with his own words so that means you need to use your imagination and imagine a context for the described behavior of form elements. Not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: Hey , thanks all for your comments, as Grigore mentioned, I still have to learn how to express myself better, made an entire new edit. Hope it will help solving it

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and [serializeObject](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject).

This is how you would do it:

```
$.post($('#myform').attr('action'),$('#myform').serializeObject(),function(r){alert('successfully did it');});
```

Comment: any libraries I should include at my <script src=".."> ?

Comment: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-misc/raw/master/jquery.ba-serializeobject.min.js"></script>`