# Nested Form Submit in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

i have two form as following

```
<form id="form1" action="/Account/form1">
 <input type="text" name="baar" />
 <input type="text" name="baar1" />
<div>
 this is first form 
</div>


// here second form starts 
<form id="form2" action="/Account/form2">
 <input type="text" name="foo" />
 <input type="text" name="foo1" />
 <button id="btnclick" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>


 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

now i want that when i click `#btnclick` inside form2 then my `form2` submit with all inputs in form2 , but not form1 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you overcome the html form nesting limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You CANNOT nest the forms. End the first form first to start another one.