# Split html forms?

Tags: html, forms

I am wondering if it is possible to split html forms?

Basically I have a normal form

```
<form action="/post.php" method="post" id="postform">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" value=""/>
</form>
```

Then I have a ajax image upload, which includes it's own form due to how it works.

Then after that I want to have the submit button for the first form.

I know I can have a javascript submit button, but that shut's out anyone without Javascript.
So I am wondering if it is possible to split a form into multiple groups?

e.g. I know this won't work, but it demonstrates what I want to do..

```
<form action="/post.php" method="post" id="postform">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" value=""/>
</form>

<!-- form for ajax image upload here -->

<!-- continuation of first form -->
<form action="/post.php" method="post" id="postform"> 
    <!-- this button should submit the top form -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean "multiple groups"? You can have multiple forms on a page (so long as they are not nested).

Comment: So basically one form split into two, I'll add to the question...

Comment: So, now you have two forms. One can't be submitted, the other will only submit a button...

Comment: It is not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve here. You have asked about what you think the solution is, but I don't get the actual problem.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I am asking is there a way to link the forms so that I can hit the submit button in the second form to submit the first form?

Comment: That's a "solution" - what the actual issue you are trying to solve? Why not have a `submit` button on the form as you would do normally? Why does the AJAX image upload prevent this?

Comment: If you have an AJAX image upload, you must have JavaScript enabled - so why are you trying to avoid using it?

Comment: The ajax image upload has a fallback for non javascript, But The Image uploader creates it's own form as well, and as you cannot have nested forms I need to close off the first form, but I need to have the submit button below the image uploader.

Comment: The image upload is unlikely to create its form as a nested one in your existing form - it most likely creates it outside the form. Did you check the generated DOM once the image upload is displayed?

Comment: Yes I did, and yes it creates it in-place, I know it is not the best solution, but unfortunately I have no choice but to use this particular script.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In HTML5 its possible as pointed out at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380229/556085:

Sample form:

```
<form id="formID" action="action" method="post">
    Text: <input type="text" value="some_id" name="some_name" />
</form>
```

And you place the submit referencing the form to submit via its ID where you want

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" form="formID" />
```

Comment: @HaroldHues I would say this is relevant: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/78/80/25/7880252a1887240607b4e3f5f672f88d.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You may have different forms which are separated via different form tags, with different ids, then you can fire the form submit event with javascript.

Without javascript on the client, I have no idea how to do it ...

Comment: Maybe in HTML 6, we have a native scripting language! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The form property doesn't work in all browsers.

I normaly make hidden inputs in the form with IDs. I update those hidden inputs with onblur in the inputs outside the form.

```
<form action="/post.php" method="post" id="postform">
    <input type="hidden" id="phone" name="phone"/>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" value=""/>
</form>

<input type="phone" onblur="javascript:getElementById('phone').value=this.value"/>
```

Comment: It seems that the form attribute now works in almost every browser (https://caniuse.com/form-attribute)