# Submit a form split over multipe divs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I want to split my form over multiple `divs`, however now only the first image gets uploaded. Can anybody see where it goes wrong? I tried adding `form="form"` to the `submit` field as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370653/split-html-forms), like so:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit-file" form="form"/>
```

But it gives me the same result (only the first images gets uploaded). What must I change to get both files submitted?

**code**

```
    <div >  
        <h1>IMAGE 1</h1>        
        <form id="form" action="update.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">                
            <fieldset id="f1">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/>  
            </fieldset>    
        </div>


        <div >
            <h1>IMAGE 2</h1>
            <fieldset id="f2">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload2" id="fileToUpload2"/>        
            </fieldset >        
        </div>



        <div >
            <h1>UPLOAD BOTH IMAGES</h1>
            <fieldset id="f3">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit-file" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is not valid HTML. It will get cludged into valid HTML by most browsers by appending a `</form>` before the first `</div>`. You can have a form with multiple divs inside of it, but you need to properly close elements within your document.

Comment: Use the form as wrapper for the divs.

Comment: Also, never give a form control a name or ID of "submit", it will mask the form's submit method so you can't call it.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed your markup like this you should be fine

```
<form id="form" action="update.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div>  

    <div>  
      <h1>IMAGE 1</h1>                                
      <fieldset id="f1">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/>  
      </fieldset>    
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1>IMAGE 2</h1>
      <fieldset id="f2">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload2" id="fileToUpload2"/>        
      </fieldset >        
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1>UPLOAD BOTH IMAGES</h1>
      <fieldset id="f3">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit-file" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```