# prevent html form fields from posting

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Since I can't find this on SO or the Web in general, I'll post it here to see if we can't add to the community's collective knowledge.

I have a legacy `php`/`html` form which contains elements that are submitted via `AJAX` and some elements that are submitted via $_POSTing the form back to itself: `<form action="thesamepage.php" method="post">`

Right now, I am excluding the AJAX-handled fields when I *process* the $_POSTed values (i.e. after I receive them from `POST`). I suppress their validation/sanitization , because they are simply not used. (In this case, abstinence *is* the best form of control.)

However, what I am wondering is this:

**Is there a way to prevent certain – but not all – fields from being passed with the `$_POST` form data at all?**

Again, I want the non-AJAX form fields to `submit`, but not the AJAX-handled fields.

I think that it would be a data security plus, if we could prevent unnecessary data – even field names – from being POSTed. Not to mention efficiency.

Thoughts?

Comment: Note that people can sent your page whatever they want using cURL and similar so you *always* need to sanitize inputs that are used, and to be prepared for anything at all to be included in the POST data.  If you have a 20-character limit for a first name field someone can still send you a 30,000 character response.

Comment: @DaveS I said "excluded", but I should have explicitly said that I `unset` those values, so they no longer exist to be either validated/sanitized or employed by a malicious user.

Comment: One trick for doing this is to have _2_ forms, with the AJAX fields belonging to the other form.  That might cause an awkward display grouping of the fields though.  Or a variation, all fields belong to the second form and script code copies them to hidden fields in the first form when the first form submit is clicked

Comment: @DaveS I was kind of hoping to avoid this, as it forces me to reorganize/reprogram much of the original coder's script… and is it ever a tangle! Make this an answer, if you want, and I'll accept. It really seems to be the best option. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveS Although this method would save me some untangling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370653/split-html-forms