# How can I put my form inside another form and use one submit button?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
  <form action="<?php $self ?>" method="post"> 
            <h2>LundaBlogg</h2>
            <div class="fname"><label for="name"><p>Namn:</p></label><input name="name" type="text" cols="20" onkeyup="EnforceMaximumLength(this,12)"/></div>
            <div class="femail"><label for="email"><p>Epost:</p></label><input name="email" type="text" cols="20"/></div>
            <div class="where"><label for="lund"><p>Skriv ditt blogg ämne:</p></label><input name="lund" type="text" cols="20" onkeyup="EnforceMaximumLength(this,40)"/></div>
            <p>Starta tråden med att posta något:</p><textarea name="post" rows="5" cols="40" onkeyup="EnforceMaximumLength(this,110)"></textarea>
            </br>
                <!-- <form action="uploadImage/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> -->  
                <label for="file">Ladda upp en bild med ditt inlägg:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> -->
                <!-- </form> --> 
            </select><br/>
                <p>Välj kategori som du vill lägga din post i:</p>
                <!-- Skapar en dropdown meny med tre värden/value. --> 
                <select name="LundaBlogg" size="1"> <!--  Namnet på dropdown menyn + size = hur många rader som ska visas. -->
                <option value="Lund">Lund</option>
                <option value="Cyklar">Cyklar</option>
                <option value="Kultur">Kultur</option>
            </select>
            <input name="send" type="hidden"/>
            <p><input type="submit" value="skicka"/></p> 
        </form>
```

---

I want to be able to use one submit button `input type="submit" value="skicka"` and I want to have my (code)

```
form action="uploadImage/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
label for="file"Ladda upp en bild med ditt inlägg:/label 
input type="file" name="file" id="file"
```

form

inside my other form like the example above.

Comment: $Ofir Baruch Hi! Because I want to use one submit button?

Comment: See the discussion here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation

Comment: $teknoid Why? Explain, please.

Comment: Toni , Let me explain myself  , Instead of using 2 nested forms , why not using one form and one submit button?

Comment: Because thats the point of using one form is that im sending all my data include my images when Im using one submit button ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Forms cannot be nested in HTML documents.

You need to either *submit all the data to a single URI* (this is the simplest option), **or**:

1. have the first form submit to one URI
2. return an HTML document containing a new form from that URI
3. have the user submit the second form manually after entering data into it

**or**, use JavaScript (with the XMLHttpRequest object) to submit your form data (this is the last reliable option).

Comment: $Quentin Can you maybe give me one example on how to use URI the simplest way?

Comment: `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="this_URI_will_process_the_file_and_the_text.php>`

Comment: Can you explain what to do with your code. Should the code be inside my another form, or?

Comment: No. You have one form. You put all the fields in that form. You submit it to a URL. You have your server side script process *all* the fields at that URL.

Comment: Ok, I did what you wrote, and now Its working. Many thanks Quentin.