# Form tag removing automatically from Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, magento-1.9

In the default magento `1.9` version, I am facing a problem with modal popup.

It's working fine but the `form` tag is being automatically removed. When I view the page source, the `form` tag is there. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="modalForm" name="modalForm" action="/test" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="text" />
        </form>
        Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gvnpf4p0/)**

Any help?

Comment: maybe showing some code will help us help you

Comment: Please check ,I have update my question.

Comment: Fiddle demo added. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: In magento product page popup is open but `from`  tag not showing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I experienced this exact problem today (although I was using Spree rather than Magento). My mistake was placing the bootstrap modal html **within** an existing form element.

Chrome automatically removes `form` tags within an existing `form` element. [See question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070339/chrome-removes-form-element-when-using-jquery-ajax).

Moving your modal window to the bottom of the body tag may help.