# jQuery Html load stripping <form> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am loading partial view through ajax call html(). I can see `response` has `<form>` tag in chrome javascript debug. But when it loads to source it is disappearing. I can rest of the html except  tag.

I am loading  under another  tag. I don't know what is the issue here?

```
var HandleGetEditPhone = function (response) {

if (response !== "") {
    $('#DivPhoneContainer').html(response);
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

You should check if you are nesting form elements, since chrome removes nested form tags.

related to your question:

[Chrome removes form element when using jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070339/chrome-removes-form-element-when-using-jquery-ajax)

[How do you overcome the html form nesting limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation)

Comment: Thank you, this was my issue. I had a modal form that ended up being inside another form. Chrome was stripping the form tags out (seemingly magically / for no reason). Needed to move the modal form outside the main form.

Comment: I had this issue and it was caused by an unclosed form tag further up the page.

Comment: Why is it not removed in jQuery 1.6 and works just fine, but 1.7 removes it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The following snippet worked for me.

```
var HandleGetEditPhone = function (response) {
    if (response !== "") {
        $('#DivPhoneContainer').empty();
        $('#DivPhoneContainer').html($(response));
    }
}
```

Do let know if it solves your issue.

Comment: This generally happens when using an AJAX response of HTML data. This answer should be selected as the best answer.