# Getting around embedded form limitations in a table structure

Tags: jquery, forms, tabular

I am aware that HTML has form nesting limitations.

I have also read pages such as [How do you overcome the html form nesting limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation)

My problem is however somewhat different and I cannot for the life of me think of a way of achieving what I want.

Basically I have a table of items. Each row has a checkbox in the first column.
The whole table is surrounded by a `<form>` tags, and there is a dropdown and submit button under the table (before `</form>`) in which a user can choose to update or delete the item.

That works fine.

What I then have is another button on each row -  a toggle button. On clicking this, using jQuery, a new `<tr>` is created and a list of transactions associated with that item are loaded from another file along with a form to add new transactions.

This form ideally should be submittable using jQuery as the point of the functionality is that a user can scroll through the list adding transactions for different items quickly and without page reloads.

The second form however does not work - the jQuery call `.on('submit'` .. does not work and I believe htmls embedded form limitations are the reason.

How would one go about resolving this - surely this is quite a common use of tabular structure?

Comment: Use a `<button>` with a click event instead of a form with a submit event.

Comment: For which, and why? Seems more like a hack than an answer.

Comment: To be honest you could use it for all of them, since you're already using JavaScript anyway. And you could use AJAX too. Forms are really only for when you need to allow javascript disabled users.

Comment: So click event, get values using jQuery, and then use jQuery post..? Is that your proposition?

Comment: Essentially yes. No point making a complicated tangle of forms when you can manage it yourself with hardly any code.

Comment: But accessing an passing various array named fields e.g date[] requires code and is a lot more complex than $(form).serializeArray();