# How can i send a parameter in a spring webflow event?

Tags: spring-webflow, thymeleaf

this is my first project using spring webflow and thymeleaf. It is also my first web project, so please be nice.

This is the situation: I have a list of items and an associated button to each of them in a view-state.
I can add items by just putting them at the end of the list,  but I don’t know how can I do to delete an item?
The question is how can I “send” the id of my item through a webflow event?

I have seen other related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280072/spring-webflow-deleting-an-item-from-a-list), but I can’t get how to implement the solution using thymeleaf
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Here is my code

My flow:

```
<view-state id="myDatabases">

    (Other transitions...)

    <transition on="deleteDatabase">
        <evaluate expression = "experimentService.deleteDatabase(requestParameters.dbId)"/>
    </transition>

</view-state>
```

My view:

```
(...)

<tbody>
    <tr th:each="databaseIterator : ${databaseList}" th:object="${databaseIterator}">
    <td th:text="*{name}">Database name</td>
    <td th:text="*{obtainDataSourceDescription()}">DSource Names</td>

    <td>                
        <form action="#" th:action="${flowExecutionUrl}" method="post">
            <button type="submit" id="deleteDatabase" name="_eventId_deleteDatabase">Delete</button>
        </form>  
    </td>

        </tr>

</tbody>

(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case, all you need is to add a hidden input with requestParam name and set its value to the current row's id. like this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="dbId" name="dbId" th:value="${databaseIterator.id}"/>
```