# How to add nested html form tags in a webpage

Tags: jquery, html

According to my scenario, The user requires to submit his/her profile picture and then get the URL of the pic and save the user profile (that includes username, gender, age and the URL of the profile pic) to the server.

The following code **doesn't work as I think** `nested-forms` are not allowed. So can someone help me solve this ?

```
<form role="form" action="/submitTheProfile" method="post" >
  <input type="text"  name="fname" id="f1-first">
  <input type="text" name="age"  id="f2-first-name">
  <input type="text" name="gender" id="f3-first-name">

  <form role="form" action="/profilePicUpload" method="post" >

      <input id="file-0b" class="file" type="file">

   </form>

</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you nest html forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation

Comment: The answer is: with the help of ajax.

Comment: Is not possible nest html forms, this dont work's because is not allowed. What are u trying to do??

Comment: You definitely don't need to nest the forms. Are you trying to achieve the following: 1) User fills out and submits one form; 2) Second form appears which user fills out and submits? If so, you can achieve what you need with some CSS and a dab of Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As world say you can not use nested form.so JavaScript can solve your issue in different way like

> HTML

```
<form role="form" action="/submitTheProfile" method="post" >
  <input type="text"  name="fname" id="f1-first">
  <input type="text" name="age"  id="f2-first-name">
  <input type="text" name="gender" id="f3-first-name">

  <input id="file-0b" class="file" type="file">

</form>
```

> Javascript

```
document.onload = function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById('#file-0b'); el.onchange = function(){   // your code... };
 }
```