# Wondering if I can nest input types

Tags: html, forms, nested

I'm making a website for my business and in this form I would like for them to choose what's wrong with their device. If their problem is not on the list I would like for them to type it into a `<textarea>`. I was wondering if I could make that text area one of my radio button options. So far I have this...

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend> What's wrong with your device </legend>

  <label> <input type = "radio" name = "problem">
         Cracked Screen </label>

  <label> <input type = "radio" name = "problem">
         Broken Camera </label>

  <label> <input type = "radio" name = "problem">    
       <textarea rows = "4" cols = "15" name = "problem" 
                         placeholder = "other problems"></textarea>              
                         </label>


</fieldset>
```

This seems like it would work but I'm worried that it will just render the text area as its own input under the same label. Any advice?

Also I was wondering how to make my radio buttons able to be unclicked. You can only activate them but you cannot deactivate them. Can that only be done with JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you overcome the html form nesting limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597596/how-do-you-overcome-the-html-form-nesting-limitation)

Answer (score 2):

HTML `input` is an "empty" element - it does not have an end tag, and cannot contain any children.

You can certainly make it **look** like your textarea is part of the radio button control, as you did, but it will not behave like it without some Javascript.

2nd question: the user does not usually have a way to uncheck a radio button. You can do it programmatically (e.g., from a button click), or have another "none" option for them to click.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest inputs. Probably best to do is add JavaScript that displays an input text field when the other option is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

**Nesting elements not possible**

Follow this to achieve what you want.

initially hide  textarea element.
Toggle textarea visibility based on radio button of your choice.

```
<fieldset> 
    <legend> What's wrong with your device </legend> 
    <label> <input type = "radio" name = "problem"/>Cracked Screen </label>
     <label> <input type = "radio" name = "problem"/>Broken Camera </label>
     <label> <input type = "radio" name = "problem" class="t_txt"/>  </label>   
    <textarea class="p_txt" style="display:none" rows = "4" cols = "15" name = "problem" placeholder = "other problems"></textarea>

</fieldset>
```

***Jquery***

```
$("input:radio.t_txt").click(function(){
$("textarea.p_txt").toggle();
});
```