# Render form in drupal separately

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-render

I want to render form in drupal separately, item by item.

```
function form($form){

$form['item1'] = array(
'type' => 'textarea',  .........etc

$form['item1'] = array(
'type' => 'textarea',  .........etc

$form['submit'] = array(
'type' => 'submit',  .........etc
}

$a = drupal_get_form('form');

drupal_render($a['item1']);

drupal_render($a['item2']);

drupal_render($a['submit']);
```

form is rendered successfully, but it seems that submit button not work (not call submit function)

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You just need to call drupal_render() one more time:

```
drupal_render($a);
```

It won't re-render everything you previously rendered.

Comment: still not working, I forgot to tell that between each item there is another form

Comment: You can't embed a form within a form. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759006/embed-an-html-form-within-a-larger-form