# How to select children and self with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering what the best way is to find children of an element in jQuery, but also include the parent in the 'find'.

Here's my simplified basic HTML setup:

```
<div id="container">
    <form id="form1"> <!-- form 1 content --> </form>
    <form id="form2"> <!-- form 2 content --> </form>
</div>
```

And I want a function like this...

```
function getForms ($container) 
{
    // Option 1
    var $allForms = $container.find('form').andSelf().filter('form');

    // Option 2
    var $allForms = $container.find('form');
    if ($container.is('form')) $allForms.add($container);

    // Should return all the forms in the container if passed $('#container')
    // Or return just one form if passed $('#form1')
    return $allForms;
}
```

I'm fairly certain that both option 1 or 2 will work. Does anyone know which option above is more efficient? Are there other options which are more elegant or more efficient?

**EDIT:** 
I wasn't happy with the *.is()* in option 2 because it didn't work when the container had multiple jQuery objects in it. So I came up with something like this:

```
// Option 3
function getContainerElements ($container, selector) {
    return $container.find(selector).add($container.filter(selector));
}
```

I haven't tested it too much, but I think it'll work for all general cases.

Comment: This might fit better over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My guess (without actually benchmarking it) would be #2 is more efficient. In #1 you are adding the container, and then filtering the whole list and *potentially* removing it again. Option #2 check it before adding it and doesn't have to filter the list again to remove it.

Comment: `var $allForms = $container.find('form').andSelf()`

Comment: @SpYk3HH: I think the point is that `$container` may or may not be a form.

Comment: @Luke, are the `<form>` elements always immediate children of `$container`, or do you want to also support descendants?

Comment: @MattBurland It would'nt matter if it is a form or not, he said he wanted all child elements (forms) and self. Thus, the filter is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! It's too bad that *andSelf* didn't take in a selector as an argument which acted like a filter. Then we could have `var $allForms = $container.find('form').andSelf('form')`.

Comment: @Luke, I have a solution that approximates that, but it works best if the `<form>` elements are direct children of the container. Is it the case?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I would like it so that the <form>s can be any descendants of the container. In fact you could call it like `getForms($('body'))` to get all forms on the page, wherever they might be.

Comment: @Luke, ah, that's too bad. I suppose forms can also be nested more than two levels deep (e.g. you can have a form containing a form containing a form)?

Comment: In this case, forms shouldn't be nested ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms) ), but this could be generalized for other tags that can be nested.

Comment: Then I can think of nothing more efficient than your second solution (provided you fix it, see my comment under bukfixart's answer).

Comment: Would this also work? `$allForms = $container.parent().find('form')`

Comment: @Luke, it would also match `$container`'s sibling forms, and it would not work if `$container` is the `<html>` element (which does not have a parent). Even if this still meets your requirements, it might prove less efficient than your second option if `$container` has a lot of siblings who have a lot of descendants.

Comment: *Rectification:* My last comment was partially wrong, the parent of the `<html>` element is the `document`, which can be wrapped by jQuery, so the solution would not work if `$container` is `$(document)` instead. My apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Your title has got little to do with the actual question. You seem to want a selector then go on to ask for performance graphs... which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is better according to JSPerf tests (Tested in Chrome on linux)

You can see the results here and the tests if you want to try it in different browsers:
http://jsperf.com/children-and-self

Note: I've  updated this test to use divs instead of forms (because forms inside other forms don't work: [Form inside a form, is that alright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright)) and we want to test the case where the parent should be added to get the real performance impact as per comment below

[image]

**EDIT**

Added third option performance as requested in comment

Comment: But in your test the container is never a form, so the `if` block never gets executed. It's an unfair comparison, I think.

Comment: @pimvdb Thanks that's very true. Must be Friday! Also forms cannot be nested so it probably better to use a different example since the title is about self and children, not specific to form elements. I'll update the tests...

Comment: @CraigMacGregor - Would you be able to test my Option 3 in the edit above? I really appreciate the benchmarking tests.

Comment: @pimvdb I've added the third option for you. Enjoy :)

Comment: Sorry, for someone reading this question looking for an independent answer, this is not it. The selector to answer the question is... ?

Comment: @CraigMacGregor Can you add my answer’s options as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really only looking for a single element rather than a set of elements, then the following should work at least as well as your option 3 and be faster:

```js
function getContainerElements ($container, selector) {
  var filtered = $container.filter(selector);
  return filtered.length ? filtered : $container.find(selector);
}
```

In case there are both descendant and root elements matching `selector`, this will return only the matching root elements, unlike your option 3, which will put everything together. If you do want that, then modern jQuery allows a simpler solution:

```js
function getContainerElements ($container, selector) {
  return $container.find(selector).addBack(selector);
}
```