# form with in form in php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to use form with in a form.
i have the following code.

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    echo "Sorry! You need to log in to add Information. <a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
} else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>iWant | in case you want anything</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

    <!--link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" /-->
    <!--link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/responsive.less" type="text/css" /-->
    <!--script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js"></script-->
    <!--append ‘#!watch’ to the browser URL, then refresh the page. -->

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-fileupload.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="upload.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-fileupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <h3>
                iWant | In Case U Want Anything
            </h3>  
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <form class="form-search">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query"> <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
             <a href="login.php" class="btn" type="button">Login</a> <a href="signup.php" class="btn" type="button">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                         <a data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a> <a href="index.php" class="brand">iWant</a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About iWant</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Contact iWant</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">My iWant</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical">
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                     <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Post Adds<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="room.php">Room</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Hostel</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Apartment</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Land</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">House</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Vehicles</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Hotels</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Mobile Phones</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="well">

            <form id="Room Details" class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="roomKoDesc.php">
            <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='clientId' value='".$_SESSION['clientId']."'>"; ?>
            <legend>Post Rooms</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Contact Number</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Your Contact">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Location of Rooms</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="location" name="location" placeholder="rooms location">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Number of Rooms</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="number" name="number" placeholder="no. of rooms">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Price per Room</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="price" name="price" placeholder="price per room">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Sqare meter</label>
            <div class="controls">          
                  <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="size" name="size" placeholder="Area of rooms">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>







    <div id ="main">

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="upload.php">
            <input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple />
            <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload Files!</button>
        </form>

    <div id="response"></div>
        <ul id="image-list">

        </ul>
    </div>



        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
      </form>

            </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

my output looks like this [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yepMi.png)

But the submit button doesnot direct to another page.
and the upload works
How can i make both the submit button work?
Is there any easy procress to use nested form.

Comment: please read this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright`

Comment: form in form are invalid code and not possible. If you NEED to nest forms in forms, you did something wrong in your concept phase.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña I think you meant this => [**please read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright) ;-)

Comment: @Fred ugh sorry.. forgot to make it a link.. My bad next time :) and second I understand also what you're trying to say :)

Comment: @DrixsonOseña No problemo ;-) it's the thought that counts, cheers

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Fixed a Fiddle link inside one of your answer btw ;-)

Comment: @Fred, Yes I saw.. Sorry I keep getting some error when putting fiddle. Checking the edit give me the hint how to settle it. Thanks Fred!

Comment: @DrixsonOseña You're welcome, and it's the same way to do it here also. *Peace*

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple />
```

Use just this for the entire form, do not use 2 separate forms. Also when the form is submitted you could upload the file.

Comment: 'header("Location: myfile.php")' this is one way of redirecting, however, you could create an wrapper on the entire form and when user submits the form, the content is hidden and shows whatever you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Enjal,

Why do you want to use multiple form in one page. you can do the same thing by using a single form. Just make use of Javascript to change form 'action' attribute. code for that would be,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeaction(url)
{
document.frm.action=url;
document.frm.submit();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit1" onclick="return  changeaction('upload.php');">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit2" onclick="return changeaction('index.php');">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```