# Laravel: How to open a form in an other form

Tags: forms, post, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a registration page, but in that same page I have to make 2 submit buttons: one of them submit all the information and the other only submit 2 of them. What I tried was this:

```
{!!form::open()!!}
//some forms where the user can enter informations

{!!form::open()!!}
// the zone for the 2 informations 

{!!form::submit(verifie)!!}

{!!form::close()!!}

// some other informations
{!!form::submit('DONE')!!}

{!!form::close()!!}
```

But I think this didn't work, because the first submit button passed all informations before it.
How can I make this work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wouldn't really be Laravel's issue - you shouldn't be nesting a form within a form, as explained here: [Form inside a form, is that alright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright)

If you really need to do something like this, you'd be better off making the `submit(verifie)` action an ajax call.

*Very* loosely:

View:

```
{!! form::open(['id' => 'foo']) !!}
...
<button id="bar"></>
...
{!! form::submit() !!}
{!! form::close() !!}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$('#bar').on(click, function() {

    information = $(YOUR INPUT).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: YOUR ROUTE + information,
        type: GET,
        success: function(data) {
            // do something
        }
    });

});
```

You could even attach both actions to the form's submit button, and use `preventDefault()` to delay the `done` submit action until the `verifie` submit action has run.

**Updated to add:** you mention user registration - an ajax call within a form is how, for instance, twitter can check for a unique username as you type on [their signup page](https://twitter.com/signup)

Comment: you should mention that your solutions requires jQuery. It's not vanilla JS

Comment: Hi i dont know haw to use ajax. but I want that middle button to take me to an other route and that it submit the 2 informations just before it.
PS: they are 2 {!!form::text.....!!}
Thank you

Comment: in fact what i want to do is this: show in google map the location that the user entred (lat & long) when the user clicks the button.
I have an other idea if I make that <Iframe> where google must appear hidden and I show it if the user clicks on a button.
I think like this it's easier but haw can I make it ? :p

Comment: @shock_gone_wild thanks, I've added a mention. As I said, very loose based on the Q.

Comment: @MehdiSayeb ajax handles asynchronous requests to the server - so if you want to send data to a route / controller from with a page, you'll likely need to familiarise yourself with it - the jquery docs are here: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Google Maps API works client-side, so you'd be loading or redrawing a map and marker on the page without having to talk to the server. The docs are quite extensive, here: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... so I looked for other ways and I found out that google map doenst have to be in a  I can send the user to an URL out of my server to see the map.
But there are 2problemes, the first is that my API_KEY is exposed, the second is that I dont know haw to get the variables that the users entered in the text field because I need them to generate the URL.
Can I solve those 2 problemes? at least the second one

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, you can grab any input's value with jQuery through `$('#id').val();` or, if they're only named inputs, `$('input[name="value"]').val();`