# AngularJS nested froms, submit button not working

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

I have an outer form that once submitted will, send the user to the next step. The inner form is submitting search requests for a table that is nested in the outer form. At the moment my solution is not triggering either of the two forms.

```
<form id="outerForm" onsubmit="submitOuter()">
    <form id="innerForm" onsubmit="submitInner()">
        <button type="submit" form="innerForm">Search</button>
    </form>

    <button type="submit" form="outerForm">Next Step</button>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/12po0xhw/)

PS my example is obviously not using AngularJS, the difference is that my forms have `data-ng-submit`.

Comment: form elements should not be nested. [More information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not have nested form on HTML, but angular does provide the ability to have them nested. For implementing the same thing you need to use `ng-form` directive.

Outer form will have `ng-submit` event, but the inner form would have `ng-click` event with button `type="button"`, if you won't change the button type then it will call the parent form `ng-submit` method.

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/12po0xhw/3/)

> [**`ng-submit` directive work only with `form`**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2513) element, so you need to specify `form` tag for outer form, since you want `ng-submit` there.

Answer (score 0):

Forms should never be nested, are you actually using Angular in your application? If so, could you please provide a Punker of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid to nest form elements, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms).

I suggest you use `ng-click` on a `type="button"` input in the inner part of your form, which handles the search, and `ng-submit` for the outer one.

I have [modified the example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XDFozVbTUx8UgJeLrTpu?p=preview) of the [angular docs on `ngSubmit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) to show you what i mean.