# Nested 'post' calls inside html

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, nested

If I add the first div inside the form, the submit button stops working. Must be somehow related to the nested 'post' calls and the different .php files.

```
<form action="register.php" method="post"> 
                        <div id="kv-avatar-errors-1" class="center-block" style="width:800px;display:none"></div>
                        <form class="text-center" action="/avatar_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="kv-avatar center-block" style="width:200px;text-align:center;">
                                <input id="avatar-1" name="profile_pic" type="file" value="" class="file-loading">
                            </div>
                         </form>
                    </div>
                    <label>Username:</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
                    <label>Email:</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 
                    <label>Password:</label> 
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> <br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register" /> 
                </form>
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: 'Cause `form` inside `form` is an invalid syntax.

Comment: u_mulder is right.  `form` is not allowed to be nested.

Comment: Ye, did not need the form anyway...copy&paste error! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form inside a form, is that alright?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright)

Answer (score 0):

> Cause form inside form is an invalid syntax. – u_mulder