# why the submit button is not working in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I tried to edit the data form but the submit button doesn't work like it doesn't have a function. In that form I also added 1 more form which was wrapped in a modal
code of view:
[image: code of view]

code of controller:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $items = Arsip::where('field_id', Auth::user()->employee->field_id)->get();

    $request->validate([
        'indikator'=>'required',
        ]);

    $i = $request->indikator;
    
    foreach($i as $row) {
        $i = indicator::find($row['id']); 
        $i->arsip_id = $row['arsip_id']; 
        $i->nama_indikator = $row['nama_indikator'];
        $i->nilai_indikator = $row['nilai_indikator']; 
        $i->save(); 
    }
    
    return view('admin.approve.index', compact('items'))->with('success', 'update data successfully.');
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use images in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

You're not very clear on what *is* or *isn't* working. It feels like your form action isn't correct. `$items`, seeing your code snippet` is a collection and not a single model, which would mean the route wouldn't be correct.

I would suggest using named arguments when building a route: `route('arsip.update', ['id' => $item->id])`

Also, you're nesting a `form` inside a `form`. This is not allowed within HTML, and there is no good reason for wanting to do this. I see that this is a delete button. You can hide a form somewhere else and [use javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) or a button (**outside** a form) with a `form` attribute to submit the form. See [this thread's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright) for this approach.