# When I delete last comment has just added I got this message "must provide comment"

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to add a comment section to my flask web app. My code works fine, but just in case I delete last comment was just added I got an apology (mut provide comment) I don't understand why I got this message while I'm trying to delete not to insert a comment. Any help would be great

Here is my python code

```
@app.route("/addcomment", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def addcomment():
 global book

 if request.method == "GET":

     book = request.args.get("book")

     comments = db.execute("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE book_id=? ORDER BY Timestamp DESC",book)

     return render_template ("comment.html", comments=comments)


     return redirect (request.referrer)
else:
      comment = request.form.get("comment")
      print(comment)
      id = session["user_id"]
      if comment:

       user = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=?", id)
       db.execute("INSERT INTO comment (comment, user,book_id) VALUES(?, ?,?)",comment, user[0]["username"],book)
       return redirect (request.referrer)
      return apology("must provide comment", 403)



@app.route("/deletecomment/<comment_id>",     methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def deletecomment(comment_id):
  if request.method == "POST":
   print(comment_id)
   db.execute("DELETE FROM comment WHERE id=?",comment_id)

   return redirect (request.referrer)
```

And here is comment.html

```
<form action="{{url_for('addcomment')}}" method="post">
<div class="row bootstrap snippets bootdeys">
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
    <div class="comment-wrapper">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Comment panel
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="write a comment..." rows="3"></textarea>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Post</button>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <hr>
                {% for comments in comments %}
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>-->
                    <li class="media">
                        <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                            <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle">
                        </a>

                        <div class="media-body">
                            <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>-->
                            <span class="text-muted pull-right">
                            </span>
                            <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>-->
                            <strong class="text-success">{{comments.user}}</strong>
                            <form action="/deletecomment/{{comments.id}}" method="post">
                            <p>
                              {{comments.comment}}
                            </p>
                            <button id="but" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>


                        </div>


                </ul>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a form inside another form, and that confuses your browser [Form inside a form, is that alright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430214/form-inside-a-form-is-that-alright)

Try use a get request to do the delete like replacing:

```html
                            <form action="/deletecomment/{{comments.id}}" method="post">
                            <p>
                              {{comments.comment}}
                            </p>
                            <button id="but" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </form>
```

by:

```html
                            <button id="but" onclick="window.location.href='/deletecomment/{{comments.id}}'" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```