# Validation of dynamic created form (AngularJS)

Tags: validation, angularjs

I try to made nested form with validation. All works fine, but when I remove one of nested form, validation continue to use removed form. I made jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/sokolov_stas/VAyXu/

When example runs, form are valid. If click "+" button, nested form will be added and valid will be false. Then click "-" button, and valid will be false all the same.

The question is: How to remove dynamic created form from validation processing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, a [`<form>` inside of a `<form>` is not valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form).

Second, you're not supposed to be doing DOM manipulation from inside the controller. The controller is for "business" logic. [See the section on controllers here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts)

For what you're doing, you'd probably be better off using one form, with an ng-repeat inside of it, and adding additional elements to an array:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormCtrl" ng-submit="doSomething()">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input ng-model="item" type="text" required/>
   </div>
   <a ng-click="addItem()">+</a>
   <a ng-click="removeItem()">-</a>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   <div>Form valid: {{myForm.$valid}}</div>
</form>
```

and the controller:

```
function FormCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.items = [];
   $scope.addItem = function() { 
       $scope.items.push(null);
   };
   $scope.removeItem = function() {
       $scope.items.pop();
   };
   $scope.doSomething = function () {
       //your submission stuff goes here.
   };
}
```

Comment: This is just example. In real world I have a large scale application. Forms adding in form by ng-repeat. I have to move my form to outside of main form. Now I have a nice logic like view stacks on mobile platform. All this because of have to edit items included in main item (editing FK linked rows).