# Routing Error, import csv

Tags: csv, upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I want to upload a csv file using active admin, and I would like to know if this is possible, create a from_tag inside of a f.input:

```
    <%= f.inputs do%>
    <%= f.input :contact, :as => :select, :collection => Contact.all %>
    <%= f.input :route_import, :as => :select, :collection => RouteImporter.all %>
    <% form_tag({:action => :upload}, :multipart => true) do %>
        <%= file_field_tag 'upload_data'%>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

When I run it I get this error:

> Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"upload",
>   :controller=>"admin/routes"}

I'm trying to call the method upload which is in RouteQuickcom class, what I'm doing wrong?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick note, that won't fix your routing problem :

Putting a `form` into another `form` is not valid HTML, and from my experience, browsers don't know how to deal with this and end up submitting the master form, but apparently there's some work-around if you really want to do it :
[Is it valid to have a html form inside another html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form)