# Wordpress post to script from post manage screen in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

So I have a custom post type that has custom columns, and in one of the columns I have a button that when clicked is supposed to send data to a script for processing. I'm trying to echo a form in my custom columns, but it seems that WP doesn't let you. How can I make a button that could submit information to a script from the custom columns. Also, I'm trying to avoid using AJAX, but if thats the only option then I'll do that.

Comment: including a form inside another form is not possible last i checked or at least will not work efficiently. Regarding form inside a form this question has been asked before [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form[/link]. Best bet would to use AJAX. What kind of processing are you trying to do if i may ask?

Comment: @dansige wow I can't believe I had never noticed that the post table was a form, good point. I'm just trying to send an id, then I'll grab the information I need based on that ID.

Comment: The form is used for the batch processing, filters and more of the table so by trying to use another form will submit the first form. If you are dead set on using a form then try the link i added to my comment or think about adding a ajax function since it's only one variable to pass :) In this case i would recommend AJAX. Clean and more user-friendly.