# Nested Form in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Model Product and Supplier.

Product has_one supplier.

how to Build a Seach   form inside a form.
,I want to Search Supplier and Put that id into My Product form.

Currently my code look like this.

```
<%= f.text_field :product_code, class: 'form-control'%>

<%= f.text_field :product_name, class: 'form-control'%>

<%= f.text_field :supplier_id, class: 'form-control'%>

<%= render :partial => 'supplier_search' %>

<%= f.submit 'Save', :class=>'button add'%>
```

Comment: You haven't specified a problem.

Comment: partial form is not working

Comment: What you mean it is not working. Any error?

Comment: is it not partialin or what?

Comment: no error show but when i submit the search form. it goes to product save method.

Comment: You have to render `supplier_search` partial after `submit` button of product form.

Comment: guys, even if it works, it's not html valid. You can not insert a form inside a form. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form

Comment: ok thanks. we can't create another form before closing the product form I am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render `suplier_search` partial after `submit` button of product form.

```
<%= f.text_field :code, class: 'form-control'%>

<%= f.text_field :supplier_id, class: 'form-control'%>

<%= f.submit 'Save', :class=>'button add'%>

<%= render :partial => 'supplier_search' %>
```

**Or**

Don't have form in `suplier_search` partial. Just put input field or whatever you want, there and submit those fields via `Ajax` and get your required results in product form.

Answer (score -1):

if its not partialing for <%= render :partial => 'supplier_search' %>
then use

"your views folder name/supplier_search" %>

Comment: the partial view is working but when i submit the form in partial file is goes to product create instead of supplier search .