# Alternative for 2 embed form?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I want to know if there's any alternative to my problem.
I have and admin panel where my customer can add/edit/delete buildings. As usual, I have all fields (title, adress, city, etc) in a form with a submit button at the end.
One of the fields is "products affiliates" which is some checkbox you can check to connect the products to the buildings.
I have a "quick add building" (jquery/AJAX) field at the end of the checkbox, if my customer want to quickly add a product at the list.  **(This is what is problematic cause we can't have 2 embed forms)**

I'm on Firefox 29.0.1 fwiw

Here's my form:

```
<form action="sql.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        [...]
        <tr>
            <td><label>Produits</label></td>
            <td>
                <ul class="produits">
                    <li><label><input name="produits[25]" type="checkbox" value="checked" /> Bière</label></li>
                    <li><label><input name="produits[2]" type="checkbox" value="checked" /> Fromage</label></li>
                    <li><label><input name="produits[4]" type="checkbox" value="checked" /> Fruits</label></li>
                    <li><label><input name="produits[5]" type="checkbox" value="checked" /> Légumes</label></li>
                    <li><label><input name="produits[1]" type="checkbox" value="checked" /> Viande</label></li>
                    <li><label><input name="produits[3]" type="checkbox" value="checked" /> Vin</label></li>
                </ul>

                <form> 
                    <input type="text" name="add_produit" id="add_produit" placeholder="Ajout rapide" /> 
                    <button class="btn-mini btn-grey btn-plus" id="add-product"><span></span></button> 
                    <span id="info"></span>
                    <!-- After I submit this form, I repopulate the above ul with the new content via jquery/ajax -->  
                </form>          
            </td>
        </tr>
        [...]
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Ajouter" class="bouton" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And here's the jquery/AJAX part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add-product").click(function(e){  // Click on the "quick add" button"
      e.preventDefault();
      var produit=$("#add_produit").val();   // Get the input value
      $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"../produits/sql.php",
          data:"sql=quick_add&type="+produit,
          success:function(data){
             $("ul.produits").html(data);  // Re-populate the ul (I output the new li in the .sql.php)
             $("#info").html("Le produit a bien été ajouté!");  // Success message
          }

      });

    });
});
```

The quick add function is working properly, but as you can suspect, it conflict with the "parent" form. If I hit enter in any parent field, it submit the child (quick add) form...

So, what's my alternative? Or is a fix is possible?
Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed [it is not possible to have nested forms in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element).

If you can use HTML5 features, you can however create a separate form outside of the main form, and link the "quick add" inputs to that form using the `form` attribute. This attribute specifies the *form owner*, which was introduces in HTML5 specifically to address the issues of nested forms. Here are the specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-owner

So your code would be like:

```
<form action="sql.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- 
      ...
      Some form elements here to edit the building 
      ...
    -->

    <label>Products</label>
    <ul class="products">
        <li><label><input name="products[1]" type="checkbox" /> Beer</label></li>
        <li><label><input name="products[2]" type="checkbox" /> Cheese</label></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <!-- Notice the form attribute, that points to the id of the form owner -->
        <input form="quickaddform" type="text" name="added_product" placeholder="Quick add" /> 
        <button id="add-product">Quick add</button>   
    </div>

    <!-- Some other main form elements -->

    <!-- Submit for the main form -->
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>

<form id="quickaddform"></form>
```

That way your HTML becomes valid, and if the browser supports properly HTML5 the submit event should be handled correctly.

Additionally, since you submit the "sub-form" in AJAX you need to intercept the `submit` event so that it executes the AJAX code when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than going to the form action. You can intercept this event like this:

```
$("#quickaddform").submit(function(){
    $("#add-product").click();
    return false;
});
```

You can also refer to the answers to this question for other possible solutions: [Is it valid to have a html form inside another html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form)
But from what I understand of your case, the form owner seems to fit best.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried your code, but it doesn't work. (Got the same result). If I hit `Enter` in the parent form, it triggers the jquery/ajax of the child form and add me an empty value in the `ul`...  
If I hit `Enter` in the `#add_produit` input, it reload the page with the `?add_produit=test` at the end of the url..  

Everything is fine if I hit any of the 2 submit button. But the problem is still there with the Enter key..

Comment: Could it be that you don't intercept the submit event? This is the event triggered when `Enter` is pressed, and if you don't intercept it the browser will try to call the `action` of the form. This jsfiddle shows a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wWYWP/. I have also edited my answer with info about this.

Comment: It's now working. As you answer, I was not handling the submit event. I had to modify the code a bit. **Important note, I think the `<button>` input interfere with the submit** so I change it to a `<a>` instead and it's working properly. I'll edit my post with the working solution, thx!

Comment: Glad that it works :) You don't need to edit the question, the answer is meant for that. If you think the answer should be edited for more clarity, let me know.

Comment: Aright, as I said, if you just check the <input> vs the <a>, it'll probably be optimized :)