# How do I include a form in a form and still control the included form?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am currently building a webpage where the user can submit an order and have the ability to add multiple items to the order.  Right now I have an order form that has the fields it needs like shipping address and all that.  Then I included the item form and closed the form.  I can't control the included form anymore.

Here is the form:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<p class="'error">{{ $error }}</p>
@endforeach
{{ Form::open() }}
<input type="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" />
<input type="text" name="shippingaddress" placeholder="Shipping Address" />
<input type="text" name="project_id" placeholder="Project Id" />
<input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="User Id" />
@include ('Partials/Items')
<input type="submit" value="Send Requests" />
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: look at this [question's accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form): `"form must not contain other form elements."`

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Forms cannot be nested.