# Rails custom update method doesn't get called in jquery toggled form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a profile edit form inside which I have button which toggles another form for changing password.

My routes look like this:

```
resource :profile do
  get '/password_edit' => 'profiles#password_edit', as: 'edit_password'
  patch '/password_update' => 'profiles#password_update', as: 'change_password'
end
```

Custom controller methods:

```
def password_edit
  render partial: 'edit_password'
end

def password_update
  if @user.authenticate(params[:user][:current_password]) &&  @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

And the form:

```
<div class="password-edit">
<%= form_for @user, {url: '/change_password_profile'} do |f| %>
  <div class="password" style="display:none; height:320px;">
    <%= render partial: "password_form", locals: { f: f } %>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "cancel and go back", admin_accounts_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

The profiles.js:

```
$(function(){
  $(".expand_password_edit_form").on("click", function(event){
    $(".password-edit").find('.password').slideToggle(400,
    function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.password').offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

However, when I click the submit button, it's being handled by the update action, not by the password_update one.
I know it's because I'm rendering this form through js and the route does not change.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is the content of "password_form" partial? I think that you are rendering form inside another form, which is not valid (http://stackoverflow.com/a/555970/2549660)

Comment: Yeah, I just found out that it's not valid html. I tried to do something which I thought was nice. Maybe I'll just toggle the password fields.

Comment: I did all this because I didn't want to call authenticate(params[:current_password]) on the default update method.

Comment: I guess validate on context would be the solution