# Why is my modal data not getting data from the form?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form and a modal. However, I want the info in the modal to be sent to the server. I have written an ajax call on the SEND button of transaction. However, the main form is getting submitted.

Here is my code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("input#submit_trans").click(function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                alert("Submit trans clicked"+""+$('form.transaction').serialize());

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "dotransaction.php",
                    data: $('form.transaction').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#thanks").html(msg);
                        $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("Failed to process transaction");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is my modal:

```
<div class="container">

        <form name = "profileForm" id="profile-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="update-profile.php" method="post">


        <div class = "row text-center">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Save">

            <input class="btn btn-danger" id="reset-button" type="reset" value="Reset">


            <div id="addTransaction" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                            <h3>Add transaction</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form class="transaction" name="transaction">
                                <input type="hidden" name="trans_date" value=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>><br>

                                <label>Payment mode</label>&nbsp;
                                <select class="form-control" name="trans_payment_mode" id="payment_mode" class="required">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                                </select><br>

                                <label>Transaction amount</label>&nbsp;
                                <div id = "div_trans_amt">
                                    <label id="rs">Rs.</label>
                                    <input id = "trans_amt" type="text" name="trans_amt" class="input-xlarge"><br>
                                </div>

                                <label>Transaction details</label><br>
                                <textarea name="trans_details" class="input-xlarge" rows="5" cols="75" style="resize:none;"></textarea>

                                <input type="hidden" name="trans_cust_id" value=<?php echo $cid;?>><br>
                                <input type="hidden" name="trans_admin_person" value=<?php echo $aid;?>><br>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit_trans">
                            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="thanks"></div>

            <div class="row text-center">
                <p><a data-toggle="modal" style="margin-top: 15px;" data-target = "#addTransaction" href="#add-transaction" class="btn btn-primary">Add Transaction</a></p>
            </div>  
        </div>

        </form>
```

My call is going to my server's doTransaction.php perfectly however, it is not showing me the form data in the alert. Please help

Comment: `$('form.transaction').serialize()` in place of this can you send hardcode json or string

Comment: Please can you show form html also?

Comment: I have update my qustion

Comment: <form id="transaction" class="transaction" name="transaction">   <script>$('#transaction').serialize();</script> and see the magic

Comment: You can use like this var payment=$('#payment_mode').val(); and send by ajax

Comment: @shivachauhan I tried that.. however, I am still getting an error on serverside

Comment: @devpro It doesnt work your way

Comment: console.log($('#profile-form, .transaction form').serialize());

Comment: Did you check out the form data is passing or not in the network mode and what is error on server?

Comment: @shivachauhan It is not getting my post data

Comment: Form data is posting or not?

Comment: with the help of devpro.. the form data is now getting posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Nested Forms`  so you can get `serialize` value by using this:

```
$('#profile-form, .transaction form').serialize();
```

But you must need to test it on cross browsers. It will work fine on `FireFox` and `Chrome`, don't know about IE.

**For more explanation here is my testing code:**

```
<form id="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="one" value="1">

    <form class="test2">
        <input type="hidden" name="one2" value="1">      
    </form>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($('#test, .test2 form').serialize());
</script>
```

**Result in console:**

```
one=1&one2=1
```

Comment: Form data is getting posted.  I am getting reponse from server as well. However, onsuccess method doesnt hide the dialog as it is supposed to do.

Comment: @Nevermore: use this $(this).modal('hide');

Comment: I did $('#addTransaction').modal('hide'); and it worked.

Comment: you are genius mate @Nevermore

Answer (score 0):

Form must not be nested. as per the w3 standard

> ```
> 4.10.3 The form element
>
> Content model:
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.
> ```

Here is the link [Form](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element)

Comment: @Chintan I want the form data which is inside my transaction modal's form not the profile-form data.

Comment: ah, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it valid to have a html form inside another html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form)

Nested form elements are the cause of your problem. I put my modals wherever I want in the document. The bottom of your container div does just fine.

Comment: I undertand .. However, I was getting my form data previously and now I am not getting the form data.

Comment: Clean up your html. Then use .submit (). Return false.