# Jquery `.click` Submits all forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form:

```
<form class=" id="form-edit_usr" action="edit_usr.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Inside of that form i have another form:

```
<button id="usrPhoto" class="btn"> 
   <img src="" width='100' height='140'>
</button> 

  <form id="uploadForm" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="uploadPhoto" name="uploadPhoto" data-usr="" style="display: none;"/> 
  </form>
```

To the "main" for i have a "submit button"

```
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Update" />
</form>
```

With Jquery i control the file input:

```
$('#usrPhoto').on('click', function(){
    //Check if user is selected
    selectedUsr = $('#choosen_usr_email').val();
    if(selectedUsr){
        //If user is selected open file dialog
        $("#uploadPhoto").click();
    }
})
```

My problem is when i press the `#userPhoto` element,
`#uploadPhoto` shall open file dialog, but it also submits my main form.

How can i prevent the `.click()` from submitting all forms/Buttons?

Comment: You have a form inside another form?

Comment: What is `usrPhoto`? another `submit` button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form

Comment: @rybo111 Yes i do. But i don't use it as a form. I use it just to use Jquery´s `formData`

Comment: You shouldn't ever nest forms for any purpose.

Comment: Form must not contain other form elements

Comment: Mjukis, it's like having an `<a>` anchor inside another anchor and expect it to work the way it cannot work :D

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Please add a closing `form` tag and it's class only has 1 opening quote mark. Please amend this

Comment: Either split into two forms, or combine it into one form, and handle the submit based on what the user has selected. Also, avoid telling jQuery to click submit buttons - just tell it to submit the form with `.submit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the HTML specification. You cannot have a form inside another form.

Check your resulting html in your browser's inspector and you will see the "inner form" is missing.

You could break them in 2 separate forms or use pure JS to upload the file.
There's a question (and answers) about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can using the jQuery submit function

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
  $('.formID').submit();
});
```