# jsp form,servlet doesn't get parameters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have form in jsp

```
<table border="1">
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.proizvodList}" var="proiz">
    <tr>
    <td>${proiz.sifra}</td> 
    <td> ${proiz.naziv}</td>
    <td>${proiz.boja}</td>
    <td>${proiz.dimenzije}</td>
    <td>${proiz.tezina}</td>
    <td><form action="KupiServlet" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="kolicina"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${proiz.sifra}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Kupi"/>
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

and in servlet in doGet method,i have

```
    String id=request.getParameter("id");
    String kol=request.getParameter("kolicina");
```

When I run this,i got error that both `id` and `kol` are null,so i guess servlet doesn't get these parameters..but i think that my form looks good..Does someone have idea why this happens?Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GriffeyDog no. The form uses GET, not POST.

Comment: You seem to have a form inside a form. That's not valid HTML.

Comment: i only have one form..

Comment: You have 2 closing `</form>` tags. The last line of your snippet contains the second one, so remove that to see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: it doesn't take value from some <select> part(i forgot to put it here)... thank you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Check this link - you cannot have a form inside a form.

[Is it valid to have a html form inside another html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form)