# Rails form_tag remote in another form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I've been following this video http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?autoplay=true and I am trying to search records in another form but don't work, How can I solve this? I need to put the search form in to create form to search records to save. this is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@cliente, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal cliente-validado"}) do |f| %> <!--ajax remote: true-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="mynewcliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar cliente</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <%= f.label :IdCli, "Clave:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <%= f.text_field :IdCli, class: "form-control cliente-idcli",autofocus: true, minlength: "1", required: "true"   %>
            </div>

<!--the search form-->
              <%= form_for("/busqueda_cp", method: 'get', remote: true, id:"cp_search" ) do |l| %>
              <p>
                <%= l.text_field :search, params[:search]%>
                <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil%>
              </p>
              <%end%>
                <div id="cp"><%= render 'cp' %></div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :Status,"Activo:", class: "control-label col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-1 " %>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <%= f.check_box :Status, checked: true %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mynewclienteclose">Close</button>
          <%= submit_tag "Create", class: "btn btn-primary", data: { disable_with: 'Creando' }%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<%end%>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain "don't work". What happens?

Comment: @Beartech the serarch form works if it is not inside another form, but when  I put it inside the create form or another form, it does not look for the records

Comment: Per the answer below, forms within forms are not standard. Could you put the search field outside the form, but show it in the correct position using CSS? If the search form needs to add info to the containing form, you could do that by having the AJAX returned modify the form.

Answer (score 3):

Nested forms (a form inside a form) are unsupported by browsers (not part of the w3c standard) and it could cause unpredictable behavior.

You can read more about this here:

- [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)
- [Is it valid to have a html form inside another html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form)